# When using spotlight programmatically from a macOS App, how to search networked volumes?

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa

I am trying to study [Spotlighter sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/Spotlighter/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008818) very good example from Apple about using the Spotlight API. It works very well for local volumes, but I could not make it work to search network volumes. I have read [Metadata Query Search Scopes documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmetadataquery/metadata_query_search_scopes) from apple, but when I set, as search scopes, `NSMetadataQueryNetworkScope` or `NSMetadataQueryIndexedNetworkScope` or both, I get no results from the query. I have four volumes mounted with smb. My code is simply:

```
self.query = [[[NSMetadataQuery alloc] init] autorelease];
self.query.searchScopes = @[NSMetadataQueryNetworkScope, NSMetadataQueryIndexedNetworkScope];
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks